# Can't access methods within an object found with FindWithTag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having problems casting objects in Unity, but I think the following illustrates my issue best.

I have an object of type Sheep which is a subclass of type Animal. I also have a class Snake that I may need in the future, also a subclass of Animal. Either Sheep or Snake may be in play at a time, and they are tagged with PlayerAnimal.  It is simple enough to gain access to whichever is in play. For instance, I've instantiated a Sheep and I grab it with the following:

```
var player = (GameObject.FindWithTag ("PlayerAnimal"));
```

I can use player.transform to move the Sheep around. But my problem is that player does not act like a GameObject, an Animal, or a Sheep/Snake.  I want to make player flash white or transparent, but I can't access its Materials/Mesh/etc because it's apparently not a GameObject. I can't access any of the functions in Animal or Sheep/Snake because it's not that either.

If I try to change player to a Sheep or a Animal...

```
Sheep newSheep = player;
```

I get:

> Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.GameObject to Animal

If I try to cast it as a Sheep or Animal...

```
Sheep newSheep = player as Sheep;
```

I get

> Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'Sheep' via a built-in conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GetComponent()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html):

```
var sheep = GameObject.FindWithTag("PlayerAnimal").GetComponent<Sheep>();
```

If all of your animals inherit from a base class `Animal`, and you don't need to access any specific properties other than what's available in the `Animal` class, use this instead:

```
var animal = GameObject.FindWithTag("PlayerAnimal").GetComponent<Animal>();
```

If you need something off of one of the specific animals, I'd imagine you'll have to test the type:

```
if (animal is Sheep)
{
    // access some sheepy property like wool color
}
else if (animal is Snake)
{
    // access some snakey property like slitherinessability
}
else if (...)
...
```

Comment: So that works, but I think my main question, then, is what is the code I used, `var player = (GameObject.FindWithTag ("PlayerAnimal"));` being handled as?  Or how do I find out?  It does not have access to GameObject methods as far as I can tell.

Comment: To clarify: your code is perfect if I know in advance that the Sheep will be in play.  But the reason I use the "PlayerAnimal" tag is that I can't know in advance if it's Sheep, Snake, or any number of an infinite number of other animals.  Once I have control of the object, it's all fine because they all inherit from Animal and share functions, but is there a way to `FindWithTag` and determine what kind of object it is afterwards? Does that make sense?

Comment: I feel like that shouldn't work but it definitely does.  Thanks so much!  You have solved a problem I have had for weeks.